# ray overlap with semicylinder in c++

Tags: c++, overlap, raytracing

I am looking for a way to find out the length of a ray lying between two finite semi cylinders.I have a structure resembles a a finite semi cylinder of some thickness which i can assume to be made up of two semi cylindrical surfaces and multiple rays are crossing the structure at various  directions .I need to find the length of ray caught in between the structure and need to implement using c++.Any suggestions ?

Comment: Your question is much too broad. Could you give a code sample that explains your particular problems.

Comment: For the math part of your question, you may want to visit http://math.stackexchange.com/.  For implementing it in C++, you'll need to give more detail about where you are stuck.

Comment: i need to design a semi cylinder in c++ and i have a ray overlapping with the semicylinder .I have the equation of the ray and i am looking foreward to find the overlap point of the ray with the semi cylinder. I am caught in desinging the semi cylinder in c++

Comment: or in short words ,i am looking for an algorithm to find  ray overlap with finite semicylinder ?